Problem with setting height for input type color
I'm doing an edit bar blueprint and I can't get my items to be the same height.  The input appears to have some sort of margin which I can't delete.
The problem
How it looks on inspect


.note-edit-menu {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.edit-menu-item {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

.edit-mode-button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<footer>
  <div class="note-edit-menu">
    <button class="edit-mode-button edit-menu-item">Edit</button>
    <input type="color" class="border-color-input edit-menu-item" value="#000000">
  </div>
</footer>



I've tried css reset and that didnt work. It's the same on chrome,opera and edge if that matters.

You can fiddle around with block-size, border-width and background-color which would work on e.g. Chrome/Edge as they currently show the inbuilt color input element, but remember that different browsers have their own styles for this. e.g. I've just looked at your snippet on Safari/IOS and it shows a rounded oblong, not a rectangle. If you want complete control of the look across all browsers you'll have to implement a color input substitute yourself.

This is due to the browser styling for color inputs. To override it first you can put -webkit-appearance: none; on the input itself and then to override the color picker styles you can target the shadow element with ::-webkit-color-swatch
Note that results will vary between browsers (ie for Firefox you would use ::-moz-color-swatch).


.note-edit-menu {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.edit-menu-item {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 2rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position:relative;
}

.edit-menu-item::-webkit-color-swatch {
  position:absolute;
  top:-1px;
  left:-1px;
  right:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
}

.edit-mode-button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<footer>
  <div class="note-edit-menu">
    <button class="edit-mode-button edit-menu-item">Edit</button>
    <input type="color" class="border-color-input edit-menu-item" value="#000000">
  </div>
</footer>




By default the browser shows input elements a certain way. It just so happens that the input:color element has some interactive parts and be default includes a bezel around the edge. The browser doesn't give you a good way to override this native styling, but you can easily just use the element in the background.
In my demo I use a psuedo element and some js to change the color of that element. The ::before element is placed using absolute positioning over the color input element. Then js updates the background color of the element to match whatever the color element is changed to. This effectively removes the bezel and lets you have your own style over the native input element.
However, it might be a good idea to check out a UI library that has already built these elements out using accessible and cross browser compatible designs. You could also just add a border to your input:color to make it more clear where the element stands in the layout, without changing the default appearance/interactivity of the element.


const inputElement = document.querySelector("input[type='color']");

inputElement.addEventListener("input", e => {
  inputElement.style.setProperty("--color", e.target.value);
});
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.note-edit-menu {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.edit-menu-item {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

.edit-mode-button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='color'] {
  --color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

input[type='color']::before {
  content: "";
  background: var(--color);
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}
<footer>
  <div class="note-edit-menu">
    <button class="edit-mode-button edit-menu-item">Edit</button>
    <input type="color" class="border-color-input edit-menu-item" value="#000000">
  </div>
</footer>




This is close to giving a consistent view cross browser, but at least on my Safari IOS it is a bit too tall.

You can simply use box-sizing : border-box; -> css box-sizing


.note-edit-menu {
  border         : 2px solid black;
  width          : 100%;
  padding        : 0.5rem;
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : row;
  align-items    : center;
  gap            : 1rem;
  }
.edit-menu-item {
  width      : 5rem;
  height     : 2rem;
  box-sizing : border-box;  /* <--- */
  }
.edit-mode-button {
  background-color : green;
  color            : white;
  display          : flex;
  justify-content  : center;
  align-items      : center;
  font-weight      : bold;
  cursor           : pointer;
  }
<footer>
  <div class="note-edit-menu">
    <button class="edit-mode-button edit-menu-item">Edit</button>
    <input type="color" class="border-color-input edit-menu-item" value="#000000">
  </div>
</footer>



